# Why this string ("ʿAbdul-Baha'"^^mso:text@de) doesn't start with "?

Tags: c#, string, char, startswith

```
"\"ʿAbdul-Baha'\"^^mso:text@de".StartsWith("\"") // is false
"\"Abdul-Baha'\"^^mso:text@de".StartsWith("\"") // is true
(int)'ʿ' // is 703`
```

is there anyone could tell me Why?

Comment: Both are `true`. Your character `ʿ` is not at the first but the second position, so how is it related?

Comment: I just tried.. both are true

Comment: What locale are you using for your comparison?

Comment: My guess is a Mono bug...

Comment: InvariantCulture Return False and True.

"\"ʿAbdul-Baha'\"^^mso:text@de".StartsWith("\"",StringComparison.InvariantCulture ); // is false

"\"Abdul-Baha'\"^^mso:text@de".StartsWith("\"",StringComparison.InvariantCulture ); // is true

Comment: @leppie i tried with mono 2.10.2 (tarball Wed Sep 25 16:35:44 CDT 2013) working fine

Comment: There's no culture which works, it seems that really the second character `ʿ` is resposible. Checked with: `var workingCultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures).Where(c => "\"ʿ".StartsWith("\"", false, c)).Select(c => c.ToString());`. If you remove that char all cultures work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the second parameter of the function `BeginsWith`; `StringComparison.Ordinal` (or `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase`). This instructs the function to compare by character value and to take no consideration to cultural information on sorting. This quote is from the MSDN-link below:

*"An operation that uses word sort rules performs a culture-sensitive comparison wherein certain nonalphanumeric Unicode characters might have special weights assigned to them. Using word sort rules and the conventions of a specific culture, the hyphen ("-") might have a very small weight assigned to it so that "coop" and "co-op" appear next to each other in a sorted list."*

This seems to affect how BeginsWith performs depending on locale/culture (see the comments on OP's post) - it works for some but not for others.

In my example (unit-test) below I show that if you convert the strings to a char-array and look at the first character, it it actually the same. When calling the BeginsWith-function you need to add the Ordinal comparison to get the same result.

For reference my locale is Swedish.

For further info: [MSDN: StringComparison Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
[Test]
public void BeginsWith_test()
{
    const string string1 = "\"ʿAbdul-Baha'\"^^mso:text@de";
    const string string2 = "\"Abdul-Baha'\"^^mso:text@de";

    var chars1 = string1.ToCharArray();
    var chars2 = string2.ToCharArray();

    Assert.That(chars1[0], Is.EqualTo('"'));
    Assert.That(chars2[0], Is.EqualTo('"'));

    Assert.That(string1.StartsWith("\"", StringComparison.InvariantCulture), Is.False);
    Assert.That(string1.StartsWith("\"", StringComparison.CurrentCulture), Is.False);
    Assert.That(string1.StartsWith("\"", StringComparison.Ordinal), Is.True); // Works
    Assert.That(string2.StartsWith("\""), Is.True);
}
```